# Search for a specific type and its children in a vector of polymorphic pointers

Tags: c++, templates, types, polymorphism

I have a vector `_v_polymorph` of pointers to polymorphic objects and I wrote a template method to collect all the pointers to objects of a specific type:

```
template <class T> vector<T*> collect_all() const {
  vector<T*> v;
  for (auto e : _v_polymorph) {
    if ( typeid(T) == typeid(*e) ) {
      v.push_back(static_cast<T*>(e));
    }
  }
  return v;
}
```

I would like to modify this so that also the instances of children classes of `T` are collected in the returned vector.

My idea for this consists in testing the relationship with a `dynamic_cast`, would you do the same?

Comment: only if the types are polymorphic, which however is a requirement also for your current code.

Comment: are you sure you need such a vector of pointers to diverse type objects? it's very jave-ish.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The vector contains sequence of elements of a particle accelerator. Elements can be many types of magnets or components. Each component has a specific set of parameters and performs a specific action on the particles beam. Sometimes I wrote a general component and then derived from it others that implement different tracking algorithms, so that's why I would like to do the thing up there. And no, I don't know anything about java.

Comment: You may look at the [Visit pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ object orientation, the right way:

```
obj->DoTheRightThing(); // does the right thing!
```

The wrong way:

```
if (( a = dynamic_cast<A*>(obj) ))
  a->DoTheAThing();
else if (( b = dynamic_cast<B*>(obj) ))
  b->DoTheBThing();
else ... // what if another sibling is added to A and B?
```

The totally broken way:

```
 if ( typeid(*obj) == typeid(A) )
  (dynamic_cast<A*>(obj))->DoTheAThing();
 else ... // what if another sibling OR descendant is added?
```

So what you have in mind is a step in the right direction
But consider making the next step too.

Comment: All the objects are derived from a root and stored in a vector because this greatly simplifies the sequential execution of a method common to all. In some exceptional cases I want to modify all the objects of a type, so I need somehow to select them from the list. In this context I think your last step is not practically reachable, don't you?

Comment: If doing the right thing is impractical within certain context, one can do the next best thing, or modify the context. Why are the exceptional cases exceptional? Can you make them just ordinary run-of-the-mill cases? Or, perhaps, can you encapsulate the exceptionality inside a normal business object? (You can, in most cases, using the Visitor pattern or a similar arrangement).

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` will work if the classes are polymorphic (at least one virtual member function).

However, it might be / is probably a better idea to not throw away the detailed type information in the first place.

For example, restrict access to your vector by placing it in a class. Then in the function that adds an object pointer to the vector of general pointers, add it also to its own more type-specific collection. One collection for each more specific object requirement.